# Hoppla, wir haben ja ein Meta-Tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Eine Frage, über die ich heute gestölpert bin, war [beginners](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginners) getagged. Nun, sowohl im [Hilfezentrum](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) wie auch im [SO-Blog von Jeff Atwood](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) wird vor der Verwendung dieses Meta-Tags strengstens gewarnt. Dementsprechend sollte es besser heute als morgen verschwinden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, das Tag ist als solches verschwunden. Ich habe ein Synonym [beginners](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginners)→[learning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) eingerichtet, damit Nutzer, da es die größte Chance hat, Nutzer, die das Tag zukünftig eintippen, auf das richtige Tag zu verweisen.

Answer (score 7):

Meta-Tag hin oder her:

- Wenn dieses Tag dafür gedacht sein soll, alle Fragen von Anfängern zu erfassen, müssten wir gefühlt die Hälfte aller Fragen damit versehen, was nicht nur ein ziemlicher Aufwand wäre, sondern auch das Tag ziemlich nutzlos machen würde.
- Wenn dieses Tag jedoch ausschließlich für Fragen über das Vermitteln der deutschen Sprache an Anfänger gedacht ist (womit es kein Meta-Tag wäre), wird es zur Zeit nicht dementsprechend genutzt.

In seinem jetzigen Zustand sollte das Tag m. E. gelöscht werden.

Answer (score 4):

Wenn man sich die Fragen anschaut, die mit diesem Tag versehen werden, stellt man fest, dass sich viele Fragen damit beschäftigen, wie man Deutsch üben kann bzw. verbessern kann.

Allerdings haben diese Fragen bereits eigene Tags, wie bspw. [practice](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) oder [learning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning).

Das Tag [beginners](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginners) stellt eine künstliche Abgrenzung dar, die unnötig ist. Es bietet meines Erachtens nach keinen Mehrwert für Fragen.

Zudem ist dieses Tag extrem subjektiv, was daraus hinausläuft, dass Fragen, die einen Anfänger nicht interessieren sollten, mit diesem Tag versehen werden, wodurch diese sich verunsichern lassen. Dies wird auch durch den [Dunning-Kruger-Effekt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning-Kruger-Effekt) verstärkt.

Meiner Meinung nach, sollte dieses Tag entfernt werden.

Answer (score 0):

Es gibt durchaus Verwendung für Meta-tags. Deselbe Tag existiert auch auf anderen SE-Seiten und erfreut sich dort großer Beliebtheit.

Im Generellen wurde der von dir bereits aufgefundene Blog-Post für eher "schwarz-weiße" Seiten geschrieben (Damals als es nur die Trilogie gab). Seitdem ist das Netzwerk stark gewachsen, und die Kategorisierung durch Meta-Tags macht in einzelfällen auch Sinn.

Ob der Tag nun ein Meta-Tag ist, solange er einen **echten Mehrwert** für die Seite bringt, sollte man ihn nicht leichtfertig "verschwinden" [sic.]

Comment: *Deselbe Tag existiert auch auf anderen SE-Seiten und erfreut sich dort großer Beliebtheit.* – Aus reiner Neugier: Wo?

Comment: Code Review zum Bleistift

Comment: Okay, aber Code Review unterscheidet sich von Grundauf von den normalen Frage-Antwort-Seiten auf eine Weise, die dieses Tag einigermaßen sinnvoll zu machen scheint. (Für eine genaue Beurteilung kenne ich die Seite zu wenig.)